# How can a script be executed for each php created element?

Tags: javascript, php

I have multiple events in a database and I want to create a countdown for each of them.
The problem is that I don't know how to create multiple timers, one for every date I get using PHP.

It works when I have only one timer and the first idea also works only for the first timer but the rest of them don't appear.

One idea is to execute the script for each element:

```
<?php include('config.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.timer {
  color: #F6F4F3;
}
.days, .hours, .minutes, .seconds {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$var=0;
$query="SELECT * FROM events  WHERE events.date<CURRENT_DATE() LIMIT 9";
$res= mysqli_query($connect,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
$formatted = $row['date'] =  date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
$var++;
?> 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
                 <p class="card-text">Event date:  <i>2019-07-20 15:27</i></p>
            </div>
            <div id="timer<?php echo $var; ?>" class="card-deck" ></div>
            <script>
            const year = new Date().getFullYear();
const dat = new Date("<?php echo $formatted; ?>");

  let timer = setInterval(function() {
  const today = new Date().getTime();
  const diff = dat - today;

  let days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  let hours = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  let minutes = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  let seconds = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("timer<?php echo $var; ?>").innerHTML =
    "<div class=\"card days\"> \<div class=\"numbers\">" + days + "</div>days</div> \<div class=\"card hours\"> \
  <div class=\"numbers\">" + hours + "</div>hours</div> \<div class=\"card minutes\"> \
  <div class=\"numbers\">" + minutes + "</div>minutes</div> \<div class=\"card seconds\"> \
  <div class=\"numbers\">" + seconds + "</div>seconds</div> \</div>";

}, 1000);
            </script>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
</body>

</html>
```

The second one is to create a function and call it each time:

```
<?php include('config.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.timer {
  color: #F6F4F3;
}

.days, .hours, .minutes, .seconds {
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<?php
$var=0;
$query="SELECT * FROM events  WHERE events.date<CURRENT_DATE() LIMIT 9";
$res= mysqli_query($connect,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
$formatted = $row['date'] =  date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
$var++;
?> 
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
                 <p class="card-text">Event date:  <i>2019-07-20 15:27</i></p>
            </div>
            <div id="timer<?php echo $var; ?>" class="card-deck" ></div>
            <script>var x=<?php echo $formatted; ?>;
                    countdown(x);
            </script>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<script>
function countdown(param){
            const year = new Date().getFullYear();
const dat = new Date("<param");

  let timer = setInterval(function() {
  const today = new Date().getTime();
  const diff = dat - today;

  let days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  let hours = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  let minutes = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  let seconds = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  document.getElementById("timer<?php echo $var; ?>").innerHTML =
    "<div class=\"card days\"> \<div class=\"numbers\">" + days + "</div>days</div> \<div class=\"card hours\"> \
  <div class=\"numbers\">" + hours + "</div>hours</div> \<div class=\"card minutes\"> \
  <div class=\"numbers\">" + minutes + "</div>minutes</div> \<div class=\"card seconds\"> \
  <div class=\"numbers\">" + seconds + "</div>seconds</div> \</div>";

}, 1000);
}
            </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a personla preference, I would first do all the PHP looping (also seprating the DB query to its own function) and add a class attribute to the timer elements. Then in the scripts part I'd get all of the timer elements with `querySelectorAll`, loop them and execute the timer function on each element. The event date could be put into a data attribute, which would be read by the timer function. All this would make the code more clear and explicit on what is happenning.

For example like this,

```
<?php include('config.php'); 

function get_events() {
  $out = array();
  $query="SELECT * FROM events  WHERE events.date<CURRENT_DATE() LIMIT 9";
  $res= mysqli_query($connect,$query);
  while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res) ){
    $out[] = $row;
  }
  return $out;
}

$events = get_events();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      .timer {
        color: #F6F4F3;
      }
      .days, .hours, .minutes, .seconds {
        display: inline-block;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

  <?php if ( $events ) : ?> 
    <div class="row">
      <?php foreach ( $events as $index => $event ) : ?>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <p class="card-text">Event date:  <i><?php echo $event['date']; ?></i></p>
              <div id="timer<?php echo $index; ?>" class="card-deck timer-wrap" data-event-date="<?php echo $event['date']; ?>"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <script>

    initTimers('.timer-wrap');

    function initTimers(selector) {
      var timers = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
      if ( timers.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; i++) {
          countdown( timers[i] );        
        }
      }
    }    

    function countdown(timerElem){
      const year = new Date().getFullYear();
      const dat = new Date(timerElem.dataset.eventDate);

      let timer = setInterval(function() {
        const today = new Date().getTime();
        const diff = dat - today;

        let days = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        let hours = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
        let minutes = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
        let seconds = Math.floor((diff % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

        timerElem.innerHTML =
          "<div class=\"card days\"> \<div class=\"numbers\">" + days + "</div>days</div> \<div class=\"card hours\"> \
        <div class=\"numbers\">" + hours + "</div>hours</div> \<div class=\"card minutes\"> \
        <div class=\"numbers\">" + minutes + "</div>minutes</div> \<div class=\"card seconds\"> \
        <div class=\"numbers\">" + seconds + "</div>seconds</div> \</div>";

      }, 1000);
    }

  </script>

  </body>

</html>
```